# Android Eclipse Adding button to an app

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I am adding a new button to an existing Android app. Here's what I've done.

Added the XML the button to my main.xml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNewButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
/>
```

And added this to my activity:

```
Button btnNewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewButton);
btnNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {
        MyClass.getValue("page: btnNewButton");
    }
});
```

There is definitely an error in my Activity and it offers to Change to btnNewButton. 
When I accepted the suggestion, I noticed it added a line in `R.java`:

```
public static int btnNewButton;
```

Also, this is underlined in red findViewById(R.id.btnNewButton); and I'm getting this error when I hover over the red X:  btnNewButton cannot be resolved or is not a field.

I think there is another file I'm supposed to add information about the button but I'm not sure which one it is.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Resolution - I cleaned my project and removed the R.java. One or both of which resolved the problem.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?Seems to be fine from the code that you pasted

Comment: So what's the problem? And for buttons, all you need to add it to is the Activity and the XML layout, nothing else. It's added to R automatically.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with how you added the button. Your call to `MyClass.getValue()` seems a bit odd though. Why all that blank space before the String "page: btnNewButton"?

Comment: I didn't see this earlier but you all are right. This is underlined in red findViewById(R.id.btnNewButton); and I'm getting this error when I hover over the red X in the activity:  btnNewButton cannot be resolved or is not a field. I hope this clarifies what's wrong. I'll add this above in my original question as it is important information. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean and re-build, possibly restart Eclipse as well.
It seems like your `R.java` file wasn't regenerated after you added the button to the XML layout.

Another option is that your layout isn't in the layouts path: is this where you put all your layouts?

Comment: Thanks for the good tip, I guess I need to clean up my project and delete R.java if I run into this problem again.

Comment: +1 This could happen if he had errors in XML - it forces R.java to recreate again.